# How to detect a "swipe up" gesture on a tab bar item?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, swipe

In the latest version (4.0) of the iPhone Twitter app, it is possible to "swipe up" on the 4th tab and open "Direct messages" that way. I could not find any relevant method on `UITabBarController` or somewhere else, could someone help me understand how does this work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a custom implementation of a tab bar.

Comment: How is a swipe more intuitive than a tap?

Comment: @MarkAdams I don't think that anyone would claim that a swipe is more intuitive than a tap. But I believe it's a really nice and clever shortcut.

Comment: My point is that a swipe isn't a shortcut to a tap. Gestures for the sake of gestures are a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: If you tap on the tab, it has normal behavior. If you swipe up, it presents a different view controller that belongs already to the 4th tab, as a way to access it faster. I agree with your point, but you might need to check the app to see what I mean.

Comment: Oh I see, this is a new version of the Twitter app. Meh.